# Run Flask App on the Google Cloud Platform (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app')

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

So I am trying and failing to get my Flask app up and running on the Google Cloud Platform, which I have configured to use a Dockerfile. I am getting this error:  line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Would really appreciate the help.

Here is what my code looks like:

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user

# Initialise flask app
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
        
    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    # app.run(debug=False)
    
    return app
```

main.py

```
#routes for other functions
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from . import db

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use Python37
FROM python:3.7
# Copy requirements.txt to the docker image and install packages
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Set the WORKDIR to be the folder
COPY . /app
# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
WORKDIR /app
# Use gunicorn as the entrypoint
# CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT app:main --workers 1 --threads 1 --timeout 60
CMD ["gunicorn" , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "app:app"]
```

Comment: That error message seems correct: it doesn't seem like you have a module named `app` (either an `app.py` or `app/__init__.py` file).  If you set up a virtual environment without Docker, can you run the same `gunicorn` command?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have tried naming the __init__ file app.py and get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you rename `__init__.py` to `app.py`, then you need a way to 'return` the `app` object.

2 possible solutions

1. Call `create_app()` at the end of your file
2. Remove the `create_app()` method and just have the code (means you also remove the `return app` command)